# Quando definir uma pergunta como duplicata?

Tags: debate

Tenho a seguinte pergunta [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165165/existem-alguma-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-first-e-single), e foi marcada como duplicata, mas quando fiz a busca na comunidade por (First ... Single), não encontrei uma pergunta similar devido os nomes dos métodos. Mas um foi encontrado outra pergunta com 
(Singleordefault ... Firstordefault) [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20560/no-entity-framework-os-m%C3%A9todos-singleordefault-e-firstordefault-apresentam), com isso a minha pergunta foi marcada como Possível duplicata de [No Entity Framework, os métodos SingleOrDefault() e FirstOrDefault() apresentam comportamentos diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20560/no-entity-framework-os-m%C3%A9todos-singleordefault-e-firstordefault-apresentam) .

Não acho que seja, pois os métodos tem comportamentos diferentes retornos diferentes dependendo da consulta.

Então minha dúvida, consideremos pergunta desse tipo como duplicata?

Comment: Só lembrando que ela foi sinalizado como duplicata, e a comunidade ainda está avaliando se a mesma é ou não ...

Comment: Até onde sei, uma duplicata não é necessáriamente duas perguntas iguais, mas sim, quando a pergunta indicada possui respostas que respondem a sinalizada como duplicata.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sim eu sei que esta sendo avaliada, mas se pergunta desse tipo é considerada como duplicata, pra mim seria bom saber, assim não criaria outra dessa forma, apesar de não ter encontrado a pergunta que você citou como duplicata.

Comment: O segundo link está apontando pra sua pergunta também.

Comment: @diegofm, então... pelo que vi a resposta não detalha o comportamento desses dois métodos.

Comment: Sim claro @MarconcilioSouza, entendi.

Comment: Os links estão apontando errado.

Comment: Corrigidos os links

Comment: relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2534/relacionado-ou-duplicata

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, vamos diferencia (First ... Single) de (SingleOrDefault() e FirstOrDefault()), eu não estou pedindo mais explicação da outra resposta.

Comment: Como mesmo falei se  First  e FirstOrDefault()) fossem idênticos não faria sentido ter os dois métodos.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza se está entrando numa vibe totalmente errada, outra coisa o `First` e `FirstOrDefault` fazem a mesma coisa, possui o mesmos problemas e são diferentes por um retorna o valor Padrão (`Default`), inclusive as explicação são bem parecidas (entre os links) e se o pessoal de desenvolvimento da microsoft criou deve ter alguma razão. Eu por exemplo não uso `Single` e `SingleOrDefault` sempre utilizo `FirstOrDefault()`, mas isso é bem particular.

Comment: Poderia talvez fazer um apontamento entre as duas questão, (não sei se isso é válido, não sei como é tratado isso, não se se pode) especificando igualdades e simples diferença. Num contexto das duas perguntas e duas respostas falam a mesma coisa (claro com palavras e modo de cada um);

Comment: GitHub NetCore: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs e https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs